# Number of execution samples

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

i am running a simple test with 10 users for 5 mins. my test has a single thread and different transactions within it. By the end of the test, there is a different number of samples for each transaction. Is there a way or a setting so that we don't start any new thread when the test is finishing, i tried ultimate thread group plugin with ramp down , hoping to see same samples for all requests but it didn't happen. Not sure if that is even possible.
[image]

Comment: have you tried wrapping all your samplers into Transaction controller? I would assume that should do the trick.

Comment: i did try that but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each JMeter thread (virtual user) executes [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down (or according to the [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers))

When you're defining test duration it might be the case that some virtual users are somewhere in the "middle" of the Samplers and they stop when they receive shutdown signal.

It means that the very first sampler will be executed with 100% of users and for further samplers the chance of getting executed becomes lower and lower.

The only way to have the same number of Sample Results for all Samplers is using normal JMeter [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and providing fixed amount of loops.

[image]

Given above setup you will have strictly 80 executions of each and every Sampler in the Test Plan

More information: [Getting Started with JMeter - A Basic Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/getting-started-jmeter-basic-tutorial/)

Comment: OP expect graceful tear down using duration

Comment: i have tried loop earlier and it works like you said. i was just trying to see if i can get it working without using the loops. I believe what i am trying is not possible without loops.Thanks